# Php how read csv file data one by one?

Tags: php, csv

I am uploading a CSV and while uploading I need to check one of its column lengths.

If column value length 3 then it should move the file into directory,  otherwise the loop will break and show the message.

Currently it's showing the message but going into else condition also.

I want:

- first it will check length of all values in csv column
- if okay then move to upload csv.

e.g in csv file column values 1 to 15 are okay but on 16th row value is less then 3 then it's uploading file because 1 to 15 are correct and on 16th row it shows error message. But i need that first it check all values length of that column then proceed to move.

This is my code.

```
        while(($data = fgetcsv($handle)) !== FALSE) 
        {   
            $count++;
            $itemCode=$data[3];
            if(strlen($invCode) >3 || strlen($invCode) <3)
            {
                
                echo $message = 'Error in length.';
                break;
            }else{
                
                continue;   
            }   
            
        }

        if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["csv_file"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) 
        {


        }
```

Comment: And what's your question about this? Anything not working with the code?

Comment: `Its showing message but going into else condition also`...that's literally impossible. Debug the code more carefully and observe what's really happening. Bear in mind that your move_uploaded_file command is outside the loop, so it'll _always_ be executed, no matter what happened within the loop.

Comment: The `else` block in this code doesn't do anything useful.  It can be removed entirely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `move_uploaded_file` command is outside the loop, so it'll always be executed, no matter what happened within the loop.

To fix this, basically you need to set a flag in the loop (i.e. just a boolean variable) which can then be used at the end of the loop to indicate whether the validation was successful or not. If you have to break out of the loop because one of the lengths was wrong, then set the flag to false. Otherwise we can assume it was ok.

Also the code can be simplified a little bit in places, for readability, and there's a typo (`$itemCode` v.s. `$invCode`).

For example:

```
    $valid = true;

    while(($data = fgetcsv($handle)) !== FALSE) 
    {   
        $invCode = $data[3];

        if(strlen($invCode) != 3)
        {
            $valid = false;
            break;
        }   
    }

    if ($valid == true)
    {
      if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["csv_file"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) 
      {

      }
    } 
    else
    {
       echo $message = 'Incorrect inventory code used. Please check and reload';
    }
```

Comment: Now it's always going into false even all values have length 3 not going into true condition

Comment: Are you **sure**? Did you correct the typo I showed as well, and use _exactly_ the code I've provided here? Have you debugged that `$invCode` actually contains what you expect on every row? You can use `var_dump($invCode);` to check what is really being used for the comparison. This code should work, based on your requirements, so I'd expect that actually the data is the real problem.

Comment: Depending on the content of your column you might want to bear in mind some caveats such as this one: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strlen.php#118484

Comment: when i try  var_dump($invCode) it's showing string(9) "CODE"

Comment: Exactly, so clearly "CODE" isn't really 9 characters long, is it? (Although it's not 3 characters long either, it's 4, so I don't know why you expect it to be successful??) But I guess you have an encoding issue anyway, perhaps similar to the link I gave - try employing the alternative suggested there.

Comment: Now i have only single row in my csv file and code is(78U) with length 3. still it's going into false condition. it should go into true condition.

Comment: Again, what does the var_dump tell you about the length of that value, though?

Comment: P.S. Obviously I don't know the encoding of the original CSV file, or the locale of your server, but it's also possible that https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php#62759 is a relevant point.

Comment: yes, it's working now. actually code value was not coming right. Now it's working. thanks a lot!